# Owin Authentication - button within form tag redirect to login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

Would like to ask how does Owin handle request within form tag, I've placed a button inside the form tag and upon clicking it keeps on redirecting to login page. Below is the code on the BaseController that I am inheriting

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ISessionState SessionWrapper;

    public BaseController(ISessionState sessionWrapper)
    {
        SessionWrapper = sessionWrapper;
    }

    public AppUser CurrentUser => new AppUser(User as ClaimsPrincipal);

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        if (requestContext.HttpContext.User != null && requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity != null &&
            requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ViewData["LocationList"] = CurrentUser.LocationList;
            ViewData["UserInfo"] = CurrentUser.UserInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly see below for the controller

```
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
    private readonly IQueryProcessor _queryProcessor;

    public HomeController(IQueryProcessor queryProcessor, ISessionState sessionWrapper) :
        base(sessionWrapper)
    {
        _queryProcessor = queryProcessor;
    }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var locations = CurrentUser.LocationList;

        SessionWrapper.Clear();
        SessionWrapper.Store("key", "some value");
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int a)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page. " + SessionWrapper.Get("key");
        ;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Below is the view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<!-- Breadcrumbs line -->
<div class="crumbs">
    <ul id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Action("", "")" title=""><i class="icon-home"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="current">
            <a href="##" title="">Today</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="page-title">
    <h3>Welcome to HSWORX</h3>
    <span>
        Good morning, John!
    @{
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <label> Authenticatd</label>
        }
        else
        {
            <label> Un- Authenticatd</label>
        }
    }</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    </div>
</div>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


    <input type="submit" value="Test HTTPPOST" />
    <button>Test</button>
}
```

Comment: If you're getting redirected to the login page then the controller and/or action your form is posting to probably has an [Authorize] attribute which required the user to be logged in. It's a bit unclear what your form and button are actually doing.

Comment: Hi Mark updated my question to include the HomeController. With or without authorize attribute it still redirect to login page. I've d check in the view if the user is authenticated and it seems does authenticated.

Comment: could you also include the part of your view with the form-tag and button?

Comment: Hi Mark updated again my question, tried adding a button and a submit type button and both those button upon click does redirect to login page.

Comment: Is that the view for the Views\Home\Index.cshtml? Can you double-check on the "action" attribute that is rendered in your form-tag in the resulting HTML. Should be <form action="/" method="post"> (if it's the Home\Index view).